# Can Sleeves of Many Garments become Authoritative Vestments?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

Can Sleeves of Many Garments transform the wearer's clothes into Authoritative Vestments? The description states "Any other non-magical set of clothing", and the Authoritative Vestments are a Channel Focus, not magical clothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes and no. Yes, the [Sleeves of Many Garments](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/sleeves-of-many-garments) can clothe you in *an illusion* of authoritative vestments.<sup>1</sup> But no, the clothes will not have any of the abilities of **Authoritative Vestments**, because you cannot channel through an item that only have the appearance of the real thing.

(Your god is not so easily fooled!)

---

1. From the Pathfinder FAQ:

   > #### [Sleeves of Many Garments: Are the effects of sleeves of many garments illusion or transmutation?](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1gg#v5748eaic9sl0)
   >
   > The effects are illusion (glamer) like the glamered weapon and armor properties. This means they can’t be disbelieved like a figment could, but they do not actually physically change the clothes. The transformation changes only the appearance, including the feel, smell, and other sensory aspects.

Comment: But is the illusion of a Holy Symbol not a Holy Symbol?

Comment: @thedarkwanderer If you read the item's full description, it is not merely a holy symbol or even symbol of rank, but has inherent abilities. Does an illusion of special clothing have real inherent abilities that can be powered by channeling?

Comment: You might want to link the errata here http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1gg#v5748eaic9sl0 because items with illusion auras can and do cause real physical effects (notably the Greater Hat of Disguise, which can potentially grant Darkvision, Low-Light Vision, Scent, Swim speeds, and +2 a bonus to either Strength or Dexterity—all inherent abilities)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Authoritative vestments are clothing.  The sleeves allow a user to "choose to transform her current garments into any other non-magical set of clothing."  No prohibition is made against the transformation into useful clothing in general or channel foci in specific. (Channel Foci are certainly non-magical).  Thus this works.

It may be noted that the item detects as illusion.  This has no bearing upon the reality of the transformation accomplished; the text in no way mentions or implies that the transformed clothing is less effective by virtue of being an illusion, or that it lacks any of the properties of the emulated clothing, where similar items tend to do so.

Comment: Do we have a hint that sleeves of many garments can transform into a warm fuzzy coat for protection against cold weather or something like that? If there's hints along those lines this could reinforce your point that the transformed clothing maintains its function. (If not, the absence does not throw your suggestions into doubt.)

Answer (score 1):

### RAW (Yes*)

Established facts and logic:

- The sleeves "**transform**"

  - Transformation generally describes an actual physical change. (Ambiguous, hence 'sort of')
- the wearer's "**current garments**"

  - Authoritative Vestments are "**ornate garments**"
- into **"any other nonmagical set of clothing"**

  - Channel foci are **not specified** to be magical.

    - Authoritative Vestments are **not specified** to be magical.

Therefore, if:

- Transforming thing A into thing B causes thing A to become (an instance of) thing B*, and
- Being an instance of thing B grants the mechanical properties of thing B*
- Items are non-magical unless specified*

Then:

- Sleeves of Many Garments may grant the mechanical properties of any non-magical set of garments upon donning the sleeves.

  - The game doesn't function without these being true, but I don't believe they are specified by any actual rules text.

### Designer Intent

The designers have stated that the effects are Illusion (Glamer).

### Setting-Specific (Nice and Fuzzy)

As the heading says, this might be setting-dependent. Perhaps the image is all-important: Can an illusion not represent the covenant between the mortal and the divine? Perhaps not, but perhaps the image *is* all-important and all that truly matters is the representation. A god of illusion or the arcane might permit their followers to channel their faith through such a device—or they might spurn them for the arrogance of attempting to deceive the one who permits such things to exist.

### And Now For A Logic Bomb

Whichever way you interpret the RAW, the game ceases to function in a sane manner. If you interpret it as not allowing them to function for any of the three possible reasons, the game breaks down in too many places to count. If you do not, consider that the sleeves are part of the character's current garments. The sleeves allow the garments to transform into "any **other** non-magical set of clothing." That is, both the current set and the previous set must be non-magical. Not only do the sleeves not function if you wear any magical clothing, their very presence prevents them from functioning.

Answer (score 0):

No, because Authorative Vestments are a Channel Focus, and not a non-magical (ie, mundane) set of clothing.

Comment: If set Mundane is a subset of Not(Magical), it does not necessarily follow that all Not(Magical) are Mundane. Even if Authoritative Vestments are Not(Mundane), this does not preclude them from being Not(Magical).